# Large facebook ProfilePictureView pictures from facebook are different sizes

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using ProfilePictureView to get large sized facebook profile pictures. However, some users' profile pictures are smaller - I think because their original facebook profile picture has dimensions smaller than those of ProfilePictureView.LARGE. This makes my page of profile pictures look a little awkward; is there any way to "stretch" this picture to get it to be of the predefined ProfilePictureView.LARGE size?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a real solution to this problem, so i came out with this workaround :

go your facebook sdk's styles.xml and edit that line :

```
<dimen name="com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_small">100dp</dimen>
<!--the default value was 50, change it to what suits you best-->
```

hope this helps ! more details on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26663008/2983862) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Backstory: My desired behavior for this was for there to be a stretch to the profile picture.  I had some issues with the direct API and resorted to this ProfilePictureView to simplify the process.  My specification required the profile image to be a circular crop of the image, so I made a mask to cover everywhere but the circular middle of the image.  This broke when I started testing on differently sized devices because the profile image did not adhere to the size given in the layout.

Solution: Ridouane inspired me to dig around in Facebook's source code since they give it to you.  In the ProfilePictureView, there is the method

```
private void initialize(Context context) {
    // We only want our ImageView in here. Nothing else is permitted
    removeAllViews();

    image = new ImageView(context);

    LayoutParams imageLayout = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    image.setLayoutParams(imageLayout);

    // We want to prevent up-scaling the image, but still have it fit within
    // the layout bounds as best as possible.
    image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    addView(image);
}
```

I changed the second to last line to read:

```
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

The image now stretches to the size of the container it is in.  Since I'm using the normal sized image, I don't expect there to ever be an overly large discrepancy that will cause significant blurring, and just a slight lowering of quality is not a big deal to me.  I realize that this is a bit of a hacky solution, but since Facebook, didn't see fit to make this user controlled, this is the best solution that I can see.  (I'd recommend leaving a comment where you set the profile id in case you, or someone else, updates the Facebook SDK sometime in the future, blowing away this change.)