# change the size of the profilepictureview : Facebook:preset_size has no effect

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to change the size of my ProfilePictureView (too small), but i can't do it via XML :

```
        <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        facebook:preset_size="large"
        />
```

I've tried small, large and normal but the size remains the same, like if that line has no effect.
Can you guys tell what's wrong with the code ? or how to change the size of profilepictureview (via Java or XML).

Thanks :)

Comment: give dp size for height n width n try..

Comment: nope. doesn't change a thing...the size remains the same no matter what value i give to height and width... :/

Answer (score 3):

in your java code you can use `setPresetSize(your_preferred_size)`

you can choose between:

```
ProfilePictureView.LARGE
ProfilePictureView.NORMAL
ProfilePictureView.SMALL
ProfilePictureView.CUSTOM
```

Answer (score 1):

been trying to solve that problem for days, i came up with this workaround : 
I took a look at the class ProfilePictureView and found this :

```
private int getPresetSizeInPixels(boolean forcePreset) {
    int dimensionId;
    switch (presetSizeType) {
        case SMALL:
// this is the line we need to edit, since the image always loads on a small size..
            dimensionId = R.dimen.com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_small;
            break;
        case NORMAL:
            dimensionId = R.dimen.com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_normal;
            break;
        case LARGE:
            dimensionId = R.dimen.com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_large; 
            break;
        case CUSTOM:
            if (!forcePreset) {
                return ImageRequest.UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION;
            } else {
                dimensionId = R.dimen.com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_normal;
                break;
            }
        default:
            return ImageRequest.UNSPECIFIED_DIMENSION;
    }
```

went to facebook's styles.xml (res\values\styles.xml) and edited that line :

```
<dimen name="com_facebook_profilepictureview_preset_size_small">100dp</dimen>
```

the default value was 50.

the result is satisfying !

[image: ProfilePictureView]